# Data cannot be retrieved for 'DataSet1' dataset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dataset, report, syncfusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IDaj.png)Data cannot be retrieved for 'DataSet1' dataset.

**Error**

> 'An error occurred while processing the report Query Execution Failed
>   For Dataset 'DataSet1' , CommandText Property Is Not Initialized '

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show some code. The CommandText is a good giveaway though that the command is filling your dataset doesn't know what to do. CommandText is usually a query or the name of a stored procedure. Also, is this .Net Core or Webforms. It feels like it should be webforms.

Comment: @RonaldHaan I've added screenshot.

Comment: I've designed the report from Syncfusion report designer and bind the report in Api ControllerApplication via ReportDataSource